# mysql DELETE rows when multiple conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

So, I have following wpdb DELETE function:

```
$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'sub_id' => $sub_id ) ????);
```

I want to delete rows where `WHERE` two conditions are met

For example, when `sub_id = $sub_id` AND `date = $date`, then I want to delete a row where these two conditions are available.

How do I change above function?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go in this direction:

```
$wpdb->query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE 'sub_id'=".$sub_id." AND date=".$date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And yeah, I didn't find any info other this method. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use multiple where conditions, than the second parameter should be a associative array. The conditions will be joined with "AND".

```
$wpdb->delete($wpdb->prefix . 'table_name', array('sub_id' => $sub_id, 'date' => $date));
```

Following query will be generated:
`DELETE FROM wp_table_name WHERE sub_id = 1 AND date = 2017-07-17 00:00:00`

For more info look here: [DELETE Rows](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows)